# Deep linking is not working for the IOS version in Xamarin.Form

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, deep-linking

I am not very familiar with the Xamaring
I'll try to implement Deep linking in Xamarin for the IOS version, Implement deep linking for the navigate my application on [MobilePay](https://www.mobilepaygroup.com/about-us) (It's a payment application like GPay, applePay, etc..) I am able to navigate on MobilePay and also able to come back to my application by using the custom URL scheme.

When a user comes back in my application first I need to check the payment status (payment is a success or failed) and based on those statuses navigate to another screen

```
 [Foundation.Export("application:handleOpenURL:")]
        public override bool HandleOpenURL(UIApplication application, NSUrl url)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<string>("AppLaunchedFromDeepLink", url.ToString());
            Vokato.Views.MainPage mainPage = new Views.MainPage();
            mainPage.Test(url.ToString());
            return true;
        }
```

The above code is my HandleOpenURL method from "AppDelegateFile" when it goes on the "Test" in that method I will update the application stage as a "BeginInvokeOnMainThread"

```
  public void Test(string value)
        {
            URLValue = value;
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(DataGetFromURLs);
        }
```

When the application comes on the main thread it's go for the check payment status "DataGetFromURLs"

```
public async void DataGetFromURLs()
        {
            var valueOfURL = URLValue;
            string[] subs = valueOfURL.Split('=');
            var responseData = subs[1];
            if (responseData == "successful")
            {
            SomeAsyncMethod();
            }
        }
```

After the checking payment status, it's navigated to the next screen

```
  public async void SomeAsyncMethod()
        {
            var activeViewModel = MyActiveViewModel.Active;
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PaymentInvoiceScreen(activeViewModel));
        }
```

The above code is for the navigation, it's not getting me any error but it's not navigating on the next screen(means it's they're sent me to the same screen they were on before the Payment))

Comment: What URL are you using? Custom scheme? Did you register it in info.plist?

Comment: Yes,I'll register my AppUrl in Info.plist file